# Geofencing based on user's location

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-service, android-geofence

- For implementing `Geofencing` I have created an app that works fine on devices below `API level 26(Oreo)` when it is in foreground.
- For background processing I have used `BroadCastReceiver` to show a notification based on user's location(Enter & Exit) as guided in the [Docs](https://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing#define-a-broadcast-receiver-for-geofence-transitions).
- [Docs](https://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing#define-a-broadcast-receiver-for-geofence-transitions) A `BroadcastReceiver` is a good way to handle a geofence transition.A BroadcastReceiver gets updates when an event occurs, such as a transition into or out of a geofence, and can start long-running background work.
- I am using `Implicit BroadCastReciever` because `Explicit BroadCastReceiver's` lifecycle is based on App but I want to notify user even if the app is not running. But If your app targets API level 26 or higher, **you cannot use the manifest to declare a receiver for implicit broadcasts** mentioned in the docs.
- Then `Services` comes into picture but  If your app targets API level 26 or higher, the **system imposes restrictions on running background services when the app itself isn't in the foreground**.
- Finally I thought of using `Foreground Services` but as per **google's geofencing docs** they have recommended to use `BroadCastReceiver`.

> Do correct me if I am wrong somewhere as I am new to `Services` and
>   `BroadCastReceiver`

Comment: You can use `foreground service` + `broadcast`. When you get Enter/Exit event you can send broadcast from service and receive it on activity.

Comment: @MD but when app is killed then.

Comment: Foreground service always stay as notification i guess

Comment: If your app targets API level 26 or higher, you cannot use the manifest to declare a receiver for implicit broadcasts (broadcasts that do not target your app specifically) So it mean I can can use broadcast for my app only?I am correct? What are your opinions on this?

Comment: Yes you're on right track